# Rails newbie need help: got an error running "rails generate devise:install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Here is the error message:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/
kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- e2mmap (LoadError)
```

All I did before this step was

```
gem 'devise'
```

and

```
bundle install
```

Cannot find any related solution online. Please give me some advice!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

Update bootsnap

```
bundle update bootsnap
```

Clear the bootsnap cache

```
go to the project home, then cd into tmp/cache
delete bootsnap-load-path-cache and bootsnap-compile-cache
```

Suggestions taken from this thread on the bootsnap repo: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the spring and then trying again

Use this in the terminal.

```
spring stop
```